# How to add the result of two sums?

Tags: sql, sum

Is it possible to **add** the **result of two Sum()** functions?

The Table:

```
  DROP TABLE MATCH;
  CREATE TABLE MATCH 
   (M_ID VARCHAR2 (4) NOT NULL,
    HT_ID VARCHAR2 (4),
    AT_ID VARCHAR2 (4),
    P_F NUMBER (3),
  P_A NUMBER (3));

   INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
   ('M01','T1', 'T2',  2, 0);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M02','T1', 'T2',  1, 1);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M03','T1', 'T2',  0, 2);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M04','T1', 'T2', 0, 2);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M05','T2', 'T1', 2, 0);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M06','T2', 'T1',  0, 2);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M07','T2', 'T1',  1, 2);

  INSERT INTO MATCH VALUES
  ('M08','T2', 'T1',  0, 2);
```

What I'm trying to receive is the points (points for (P_F) and points against(P_A)) of the home team "T1".

To make it slightly more clearer, I do the following of which yields a total of **9**.

```
 select sum(P_F)
 from match
 where HT_ID='T1';

 select sum(P_A)
 from match
 where AT_ID='T1';
```

I tried the following but it adds both columns for that particular team, **resulting 17**:

```
 select sum(P_F+P_A)
 from match
 where ht_id='T1' or at_id='T1';
```

How could I **add** the **two sums** in one query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
sum(case when HT='T1' then P_F else 0 end), 
sum(case when AT='T1' then P_A else 0 end)
from match
```

to add:

```
select
sum(case when HT='T1' then P_F else 0 end) +
sum(case when AT='T1' then P_A else 0 end)
from match
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CASE inside your sum:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ht_ID = 'T1' THEN P_F ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN AT_ID = 'T1' THEN P_A ELSE 0 END)
FROM    Match
WHERE   ht_id='T1' 
OR      at_id='T1';
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81dc3/2)**